# Auto-responding to http traffic on local computer

Tags: c#, http, fiddler

I am looking for a small utility that can perhaps sit in the tray that functions similar to Fiddler's Auto-Responder.  I would be willing to write such a utility that supports taking a request and responding with data located in a file containing the response headers/body.  I am writing an application is C# that would benefit from such a utility.

If there is no such utility, could someone point me in the right direct for beginning to write such an application?  I ask because I figured someone out there probably knows and would point me in the right direction in no time.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained what's wrong with simply using Fiddler itself? If you run it using the -quiet command line argument, it sits quietly in the tray.

If you want to write your own application in C#, you can do so using FiddlerCore; see http://www.fiddler2.com/core/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Typically we call this a web server. They listen for web traffic and automatically respond to it with a file, typically a webpage. Apache is cheap. I think MS has a free IIS package too.